# CrossRider - is it possible to check what is the current version number?

Tags: crossrider

Can the extension check it's own version number and does it change between platforms (browsers)? And is it possible to specify a specific version number for the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that [appAPI.appInfo.version](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.appInfo-property-version) is what you're after to obtain the extension's own version number. To create you own version number, simply save it as a JavaScript variable in your code.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Is it possible to specify a specific version number for the extension, instead of the version number given by CrossRider?

Comment: I believe I answered that. Simply create your own version number as a variable in your code.